# The file “Pods-xxx.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file: /Pods appears twice in my configuration paths

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have different targets, hence different configurations in my app.

Every time I run `pod install`, I end up having a debug and a release warning for each configuration, telling me that :

> The file “Pods-{MyTarget}.debug.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
>
> /{MyAppPath}/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-{MyTarget}/Pods-{MyTarget}.debug.xcconfig

It appears that `/Pods` is being added twice in the configuration paths (from Info section at project level), and I have no idea why:

[image]

But to solve this issue, I simply have to manually select the option that's below, and it's OK:

[image]

[image]

Then the warning disappears and I am able to build the project again.

What's causing this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `pod deintegrate` help?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I tried it, sadly without success.

Comment: Does the "Pods" string show up in the deintegrated {project}.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Yes it does, under `/* Begin PBXGroup section */`, I have this block: `7BC2F4AD41049584------- /* Pods */ = {
   isa = PBXGroup;
   children = (
   );
   path = Pods;
   sourceTree = "<group>";
  };`

Comment: Try backing up the file, deleting that block, and rerunning `pod install`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien It worked! Thanks so much ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Listing the answer we worked out in the comments:

- Run `pod deintegrate`
- Back up the {project}.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file
- Search for `Pods` in the file
- Delete any blocks that include `Pods`
- Rerun `pod install`

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks!! It worked for MS AppCenter automated builds.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: for me i run "pod install --repo-update" and worked.

Comment: yes `pod install --repo-update` worked for me